# CloudFormation Global Resource deployment across multiple regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to deploy this CloudFormation template across my organization that contains global resources as well as Region-specific. I have seen several methods pertaining to my issue but none seem to work as I was hoping. I pieced my script together with other StackOverflow answers that I can't find the links to right now, but most pointed to this handy link:  https://garbe.io/blog/2017/07/17/cloudformation-hacks/

Here is how I have essentially pieced my script together (broken up for easier reading):

```
Parameters:
  CommercialMaster:
    Description: The Commercial Account ID for routing.
    Type: String
    Default: ############
  GovCloudMaster:
    Description: The GovCloud Account ID for routing.
    Type: String
    Default: ############
  LambdaRoleName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'LambdaR53Role'
```

```
Conditions:
  Commercial: !Equals [ !Ref AWS::Partition, 'aws' ]
  RegionCheck: !Or [!Equals [!Ref AWS::Region, 'us-east-1'], !Equals [!Ref AWS::Region, 'us-gov-west-1']]
  CreateLambdaRole: !Equals [ !Ref LambdaRoleName, 'false' ]
  CreateLambdaRoleRegion: !And
    - !Condition RegionCheck
    - !Condition CreateLambdaRole
```

```
Resources:
  LambdaPermissionsRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Condition: RegionCheck
    Properties:
      RoleName: LambdaR53Role
      Description:  Lambda permissions role for R53 association.
```

```
CreateRoleWaitHandle:
    Condition: CreateLambdaRole
    DependsOn: LambdaPermissionsRole
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle
#added, since DependsOn: !If is not possible, trigger by WaitCondition if CreateLambdaRole is false
  WaitHandle:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle
#added, since DependsOn: !If is not possible
  WaitCondition:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition
    Properties:
      Handle: !If [CreateLambdaRole, !Ref CreateRoleWaitHandle, !Ref WaitHandle]
      Timeout: "1"
      Count: 0
```

```
  AssociateVPCs:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    DependsOn: WaitCondition
    Properties:
```

Obviously, because of the hardcoded `AWS::Region` this works fine when deploying out to `us-east-1` for Commercial, but when deploying with a StackSet, it fails in any other region. If I remove the `RegionCheck` then the stack fails because it tries to create the Role in every region and realizes that it already exists (because IAM is global, obviously).

My question, the part I'm stuck on, is how I can create the global IAM role, and STILL deploy the lambda function out to each region I need it (4 regions)?

My temporary solution, which I don't like is to essentially hardcode the region on to the back of the role name, like so:

```
Resources:
  LambdaPermissionsRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Condition: CreateLambdaRole
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub LambdaR53Role-${AWS::Region}
      Description:  Lambda permissions role for R53 association.
```

Any further guidance would be great, but this headache has given me the push to start examining Terraform as my way forward so things can be more consolidated.

Comment: You should split the stack into global resources such as iam roles, and then deploy the rest.

Comment: Do you have to specify the RoleName (as a business requirement)?  If not, it would create the Role in each stack, giving each a different name.

Comment: @Marcin I would like to consolidate into as few stacks as possible. I know Terraform is able to do this successfully in a single script which is why I am considering it.

Comment: @Tim - I do have to make sure the name has specific prefixes for security purposes (i made a generic role name for this post, not the actual name the final result would have) as we lock down customer accounts to not be able to touch certain resources. But i also want to avoid having multiple roles with region suffixes.

Comment: @JustinLawhorne In TF you could do it, but not in CFN. Splitting your template is the only way to do it, if you don't want to develop custom resources to manage IAM role creations and updates.

Comment: I agree with @JustinLawhorne.  If you have to control the name and you cannot have multiple, you're going to need to split the templates up.